# How to determine what SQL query a java web application is using to return the data?

Tags: java, oracle, web

I have been given a java web application for which I have the source code to.  The application queries an Oracle database to return data back to the user in web page.  I need to update a value for the returned data in the database, without knowing the table or column names.  Is there a general way to determine what query the application is submitting to return the data for a particular page so I can find the right tables and columns?

I am new to java and web development so not sure where to start looking.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's always the old fashioned way of finding out. You can find the source code for the specific page you're looking at and identify the query that's being executed to retrieve the data. I'm assuming that's not what you're looking for, though.

Some other options include using [JDBC (Enabling and Using JDBC Logging)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm) logging feature or [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) (the JDBC probe shows you all SQL statements in the events view). Once you find the SQL statement, you can use standard text search features within your IDE to locate the specific code and make alterations.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, I am looking to go the old fashioned way.  I have the page source and the java application source files.  But I'm having a hard time identifying the query the page is using.  This may be attributed to my lack of programming experience.  But if you can expand upon this method in any way, that would be great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The method used for identifying the query will vary depending on the technology used to develop the web application (most likely either JSP or Servlets) as well as how the application is designed. Usually, but not always, the page URL can be mapped to a specific file where the HTML is generated. In that file you should find code which invokes a query and then writes the results to the output stream. In cases where there is no obvious or direct mapping between the URL and the code, text searches will often lead you in the right direciton. Try searching for content found on the page, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a controlled test (e.g., you are the only person on that web application), you could turn on SQL tracing on the DB connection and then run your transaction several times. To do this

- look at all the connections from that application using v$session -- you can control this by tweaking your connection pool setting (e.g., set min and max connection to 1). Assuming this is your test environment.
- turn on 10046 trace (see https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof -- there are many other examples).

The 10046 trace will show you what the application is doing -- SQL by SQL. You can even set the level to 12 to get the bind variable values (assuming you are using prepared statements).